# Middle click in Windows 7 on a Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, macbook, macbook-pro

For some indecipherable reason, my company gave me a Macbook Pro so I can do .net development in Windows 7 via Bootcamp. (I hate this thing.)

Is there any way to perform a middle click in Windows 7 from a Macbook Pro?

Comment: Somebody's awfully negative! Also, is this a Unibody, or does it have a physical click button?

Comment: The whole pad clicks. There is no separate button. 

You're right about the negativity. I'm not at all happy about being given the wrong tool for the job, which I'll likely be stuck with for the next few years. I would have preferred a budget $300 notebook from Best Buy over this thing.

Comment: I was a mechanic for 30 years, I had to buy my own tools, you might consider investing in your own notebook and hardware to do your job well.

Comment: @Moab: I would if I could, but you run into issues as a Software Engineer such as software licensing, network security, etc. Many places will not even let you connect your personal notebook to the company's network for security reasons.

Comment: Do you know why they issue a MAC for Windows development? Have you asked for a Windows PC, or is this suicide at that company?

Comment: The CEO told me, "You can't beat the hardware," but I priced a Dell with the exact same specs for $1140 less. That was the most reason I was given. Today was my first day. I figure I'll wait until I've felt things out and built up some good will before I see about getting a PC down the road.

Comment: Does a two-finger click work?

Comment: @Moab MAC = Media Access Control, Mac = Macintosh Computer (I know I'm anal about it, but it really irks me).

Comment: @squircle, yes you are.

Comment: @emb1995: Two finger click did not work.

Comment: @Craig_M Last test: two-fingers on the track pad + SPACE + track pad click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/) and a VM to do this.

Comment: That's a MacOS tool. OP is using Windows.

Comment: OP posted the answer.

Comment: Oh. Right. I should probably read those things :).

Answer (score 0):

**I bet you can configure that as a 3-fingered click in your Boot Camp settings from within Control Panel. That'd likely be in the mouse tab and a gesture you can configure very easily.**

It's entertaining to me, how crazy people get about this kind of thing. I personally like Apple hardware. It's expensive and generally very well made. I like OSX, but I run Ubuntu on all my machines. It's a personal preference thing really. Suffice to say, the hardware is able, just a matter of seeing how. This said, I'm not especially fond of Apple's policies, but meh, whatever, it's all just stuff.. Stuff that can be manipulated.

If you're really old school, you can always roll with a USB mouse.. You should be able to find a decent OEM one for $10. Anyway, I'm not sure I've had a single x86 laptop with a dedicated middle mouse button integrated..... But who really cares anyway..

Comment: The ergonomics are terrible with the giant track pad that pushes the KB back. The Alt and Win key positions are swapped. The video resolution options are limited. I have no middle click. It makes me crazy that they spent $2400 on a computer I have to screw with to make it do what I need instead of spending half the price for a similarly equipped PC that just does what I need. For someone who writes code all day in a Windows environment, this is not the right tool. There is no option for configuring middle click in the Bootcamp configuration, btw.

Comment: Well, I may not share your feelings, but I do agree that a developer should be given the hardware they feel equips them well to do their work. Too bad you can't get by with an external keyboard and mouse. When I'm on a coding stint, I can't stand to be confined to laptop peripherals, generally.